# to_json in Ruby without quotes around keys

Tags: ruby

The following two lines produce the same output:

```
1.9.3p327 :015 > {:key=>1234}.to_json
=> "{\"key\":1234}" 
1.9.3p327 :016 > {"key"=>1234}.to_json
=> "{\"key\":1234}"
```

Which is the following json:

```
{
  "key" : 1234
}
```

How can I get it to produce `"{key:1234}"`?

Comment: Is it safe to assume that you're using the `json` gem to get the `to_json` functionality?

Comment: Any particular reason you want to do this? JSON specifies that keys should be quoted strings. The unquoted syntax is valid Javascript, but not valid JSON, as far as I know.

Comment: Also, there's no equivalent to ruby's symbols in JSON or Javascript, so symbols are always converted into strings. You can't get the original (symbol-keyed) hash back from JSON.

Comment: I just wanted to add a small comment -- on client side use `JSON.parse(<payload>)` to get your JavaScript object from JSON e.g. `var myObject = JSON.parse('{ "key": 1234 }')`

Comment: In case anyone wants to implement it, here is the line where the quote is added - https://github.com/flori/json/blob/b3ec252120f4a5c12de3ffcf16b2540bdea79248/lib/json/pure/generator.rb#L304 ... the library uses itself to render the string, which unfortunately makes this hard to monkey-patch.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The output you want to achieve is not JSON. It is illegal. It seems kind of obvious that the JSON library will produce JSON output not something which is not JSON.

If you want to output something which is not JSON you need to use a library which is not JSON. In this particular case, it looks like you made up the output format, so you'll probably have to write the library yourself.

Comment: Thanks, as it is valid JavaScript I thought I was valid json too.

Comment: JSON is a standard. It's possible to create something valid in a language that resembles valid JSON but isn't, but, if you intend to transfer the data stream from language to language using JSON parsers, you'll have to toe the line and follow the specs, and, the easiest way to do that is live with the default outputs. Sometimes data compatibility between systems is a pain, but there are some *minor* benefits making it worthwhile.

Answer (score 2):

The other poster is correct about it not being valid JSON. I just wanted to copy a ruby object from my console into my code using colons instead of hash rockets

In this context you can use: https://github.com/awesome-print/awesome_print

```
ap({key: 1234}, ruby19_syntax: true, index: false)
```